# Cannot change value of dynamically created textbox

Tags: javascript, variables, textbox, dynamically-generated

I have been trying various means of doing this all day, and nothing has done the job yet. What I have is a text box that is part of a dynamically generated HTML table... users can add rows or delete them. In this instance I would like for users to be able to enter a value into the text box, and when the focus changes from the box to another part of the table I would like it to save the changed value in the place of the default value. No matter what I try the value always remains blank. Here's the dynamically generated table element:

```
function ...() {

    var addText = document.createElement('input');
            addText.setAttribute('type','text');
            addText.setAttribute('name','comment');
            addText.setAttribute('id','text');
            addText.setAttribute('value','');
            addText.setAttribute('onblur','changeText(this)');

...
}
```

and the function changeText():

```
function changeText () {
    var comment = getElementById('text').value;
    /* How to get it back? */
}
```

I can see that the problem (I think) is that I am not getting `comment` back to correct spot in the calling function but the solution is eluding me!

Comment: So where is comment supposed to go, right now it's just a local variable that does nothing? How do you "save" the value?

Comment: Sorry, could have been a bit more clear there. `comment` is supposed to pass back to `addText.setAttribute('value','');` and replace the blank value. I am about to edit to try the below solution. I am aiming to save the value itself to local storage.

Comment: But the value changes when someone types in a value, you don't have to pass back anything, it's the same element?

Comment: That's what I thought as well, but after checking the textbox value passed to DOM storage after entering text, the value remains unmodified. So apparently I need some function to rewrite the changed value to the text element before saving to DOM storage. This is where I have gotten stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change this line

```
var comment = getElementById('text').value;
```

to

```
 var comment = document.getElementById('text').value;
```

Comment: In addition to my answer above, this.

Comment: Sorry Praveen... I somehow missed your answer way back when! I finally arrived at this conclusion, but I thought it only proper to (finally) mark it as answered after taking so long.

Answer (score 1):

You're setting the same id multiple times.  Id is a unique identifier.  You want class.  That's part of your problem.  Also your function isn't receiving 'this'.  So that's a problem.